# C# dictionary or just keep using lists?

Tags: c#

I'm using a list to store a pair of hexadecimal values (eg. in the list AD38F2D8, displayed as:Value_A: AD 38 F2 D8).

My question is should I use a `Dictionary<string, string>` or should I use  `Dictionary<string, NewCustomObject>` to store the hexadecimal string as a pair of strings. (Value: [AD, 38, F2, D8]) instead of (Value: AD38F2D8).

It probably won't make to much of a difference between the two.

With `Dictionary<string, string>` I would just store each hex string in the dictionary, and then split them up in their respective pairs when I need them. 
if I use the `Dictionary<string, NewCustomObject>` I would end up first splitting the hex strings in their respective pairs and then store them in the dictionary.

My question is which should I use? Or should I just keep using lists?

It's not entirely necessary for me to use `Dictionary<string, string>` as I would still know which index what string is on, just that it would look nicer.

List example:

```
Index = 0,  Value = 3D95FF08
Index = 1,  Value = 8D932A08
```

`Dictionary<string, string>` example:

```
Index = 0, Key = First,  Value = 3D95FF08
Index = 1, Key = Second, Value = 8D932A08
```

`Dictionary<string, NewCustomObject>` example:

```
Index = 0, Key = First,  Value = 3D, 95, FF, 08
Index = 1, Key = Second, Value = 8D, 93, 2A, 08
```

NOTE: the Index value in each dictionary example is just to show the corespondence to the others, I know a dictionary does not have Index values but uses keys instead. it's just makes it easier to look at this example.

I came across the last Dictionary string here: [C# Dictionary with two Values per Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500835/c-dictionary-with-two-values-per-key)
I was searching for it as I have used that way several times while writing python code. by storing a list of strings within a dictionary.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT**

Each string in either the list or dictionary, would be split in their respective bytes. 
EG.

```
BYTE   0   1   2   3 to  6 .....
HEX    AD  12  01  0000859D  .....
```

Byte 0 would hold the Index 
Byte 1 would hold the Reference
Byte 2 the Flags
Byte 3 to 6: The Memb_Number_ID

Therefore, if I split them up before possibly putting these in the dictionary I don't have to do it before I use them in their respective place as I would have to split them up to calculate the index, reference and flags.

The database was given to me in this format, I am forced to work with it the way it currently is, so i can not change it. and can only adapt my code to it.

above example would be outputted as:

```
Index  Reference Link    Flags          Memb_Number_ID
173     18               +A             John (ID: 34205)
```

Comment: Why do you think about switching to Dictionary? Isn't the code with the lists working?

Comment: If you let us know how you intend to use the collection, someone will provide a code sample along with a recommendation.  At the moment, you've only told us what you are storing, not how you intend to access it later.

Comment: The code with the lists is working fine, i'm just looking for a way to make it abit easier to work with. each Hexadecimal value is stored in the database as 1 string, but as explained above each set of characters within that string have their own meaning, therefore putting it in a dictionary with the split up pairs might make things easier, to display the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries do not expose indexes, they don't have the concept.  I'd stick with a list:

`List<NewCustomObject> myHexValues;`

And if you need to search through it, you can use LINQ.  Only use dictionaries if you need fast access based on a defined key.

You haven't really stated how you intend to use the collection, so no one can really tell you to use one or the other as yet - I'm only guessing based on the fact you want index values.

**Update:** if you want easier access to elements of the hex value, you can either use a [rectangular array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or wrap the value in a custom type and expose properties for the different parts (your choice on `struct` vs `class`, depends on the values I suppose), and then stick that type in a list.

If you make your own type, you can [expose an indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you wish to get the following syntax:

`myCustomType[indexKey] = value;`

Comment: actually the index is just there to show the corresponces to the list. i don't need the indexes. it's just either i would do like myhexvalues[0] or myhexvalues[1]. or the dictionaries respective method

Comment: @Raskaroth how do you want to use the collection?  Ignore for a moment what collection you will eventually use.  Do you want to key information out or iterate?

Comment: If you want to "index" them out, as in, use a value that isn't the "key" of the dictionary, then you can't, you need to use indexes.

Comment: I added additional information, I hope that will explain it more clearly.

Comment: Thank you, using an rectangular Array would suit the program best I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to associated two (or more) values to each other, a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) is what you need. A dictionary is unnecessary because you aren't using the one of the values as a lookup (key)... are you?

Based on what I think you're situation is, I'd say a collection (list works fine) of Tuples.

Also, why are you storing a Hex value as a String? You can leave it as an integer and use `String.Format({0:X}, value);` to display it as a Hexidecimal String.

Comment: Because initially it is stored in the database as a binary, and i use a method explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640898/c-asp-net-show-binary-data-from-database .

This is pretty much a continuation of that code, just now that i'm splitting it up to work further with it. it works, but i'm looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: and no I'm not using the key to lookup the value, I don't necessarily have to. Forgot about tuple's though, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Tupple's would not work, as the hexadecimal values are stored 1 after the other, therefore if i have 8 strings stored in that database, and each string contains 8 pairs of hexadecimal values. then i would have a tupple of: 8 * ( 8 * 2 ) = 128 values.

And my database stores 80 strings of hexadecimal in one database value, imagine how big that tupple would be? or I would need to create 80 individual tupple's with 8 pairs of hex values in them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not parse the hex string immediately you get it into a real object? You've demonstrated what the object looks like (with the index, reference links, etc.). I'd personally parse it straight up into a Record object (or something like that) and then store them in a List. That way its much easier to query them as well as being in a more intuitive format than storing a hex string or array of hex strings or whatever...

Comment: Thing is 1 hex string from the database contains 80 strings, which contain 8 pairs. that's why i need something more easily usable.